# Deploying an Angular app to a Weblogic server

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle, servlets, weblogic

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy an Angular.js app to a Weblogic server and am getting stuck. The goal is to have a Java Servlet running a REST API to communicate with the weblogic server while the Angular app serves up the front-end.

Typically, I used a gulpfile to build my Angular application and bower to manage the dependencies. I can't figure out how to fit the Java Servlet into the build though, and what to do about deploying the app to the weblogic server.

I [read that grunt and bower can be used](http://kofler.nonblocking.at/2014/05/bringing-the-java-and-javascript-world-together/) to generate Maven files which would then be installed as artifacts on the local repository, but it isn't making much sense to me. Has anyone done something similar to this before and have advice?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. all right!?

I'm currently having to develop applications in AngularJS to be used in an application server. Specific tasks that the Gulp can provide, I will be flawed if i try to say something as use Grunt (grunt-contrib-war), but on the issues architecture're, i created e install 2 aplications to the weblogic, usually with CrossOrigin defined between them. therefore its development is separated, Service layers and consumption layer.

In a larger scope could consider using:

- Service-web
- Service-oauth
- Service-rs
- ApplicationA
- ApplicationB

P.S .: Searching in npm to found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-war